# Errno 150 in MySQL with Foreign Key Matching Datatype

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making the following SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE discography (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    musician_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    album_cover_url varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    year INT(11),
    FOREIGN KEY (musician_id) REFERENCES musician (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The id on the musician field that the foreign key musician_id is referencing looks like this:

```
 id                   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
```

It thus seems like I'm using a matching datatype for musician_id. Yet I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'discography' (errno: 150)
```

Indicating an issue with the foreign key. What's up with that?

Comment: Can you try this `musician_id int(11) NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

***Check out the MySQL manual about [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) constrains:***

*`If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error message.`*

***A few ideas:***

*1. Better drop the tables and create it new with a well formed syntax.*

*2. Make sure to add `ENGINE=InnoDB;` to your `CREATE TABLE - command`.*

*3. Make sure InnoDB is enabled on your MySQL server. To verify this,
    try this command:*

```
SHOW `VARIABLES LIKE` 'have_innodb'; - if it returns
a YES, then InnoDB is enabled.
```

*4. Check your command for upper- and lowercases in table- and
    fieldnames.*

*5. Check this not only one the table you want to create, but also on
    the tables the foreign keys are referring to.*

*6. Make sure your referred tables are properly indexed.*